# Is it possible to turn a button into a variable?

Tags: c#, button

I have a code in C# with 26 button in it and I want them to all be disabled until the user does something, but I dont want to copy/paste button1.Enable = false; Button2.Enable = false...
So is there a way to do something like this :

```
   for (int i = 1; i < 26; i++)
   {
   button+i.Enable = false;
   }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Put them in an array, find them by name in a controls collection, use reflecting, pick one. There are probably a lot more options than I have given. What kind of project is it, web? winforms? wpf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using either of `Controls.Find` or `Controls.OfType<Button>()` only works at run-time. I prefer a statically checkable compile-time approach. Then if you delete a button on the form the code won't compile. Helps give you that type-safe feeling.

I do it this way. Start with a field to hold the buttons in an array:

```
private Button[] _buttons = null;
```

Set the array once in your initialization code:

```
_buttons = new[] { button1, button2, button26 };
```

Then when you need to do something with the buttons you just do this:

```
foreach (var button in _buttons)
{
    button.Enable = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to iterate buttons directly.

```
foreach(var button in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
   button.Enable = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Form.Controls.Find()`

```
for (int i = 1; i < 26; i++)
{
    this.Controls.Find("button" + i, searchAllChildren: false).Enable = false;
}
```

The code assumes your buttons are named `button1` through `button26`.

It's not possible directly like you are, but that doesn't make sense anyway.

Comment: If it is winforms/wpf  this can work, but it is a guess.